# Bison example code not compiling

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, bison

I'm reading LFS and came across **bison** which I've seen it before other places so I thought I should learn a bit more about it. I found [this page from UC Riverside CS department](http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~lgao/teaching/bison.html) and the example code is not working. Anyone know whats wrong? For convenience I pasted the code:

**calc.lex** file:

```
/* Mini Calculator */
/* calc.lex */

%{
#include "heading.h"
#include "tok.h"
int yyerror(char *s);
int yylineno = 1;
%}

digit       [0-9]
int_const   {digit}+

%%

{int_const} { yylval.int_val = atoi(yytext); return INTEGER_LITERAL; }
"+"     { yylval.op_val = new std::string(yytext); return PLUS; }
"*"     { yylval.op_val = new std::string(yytext); return MULT; }

[ \t]*      {}
[\n]        { yylineno++;   }

.       { std::cerr << "SCANNER "; yyerror(""); exit(1);    }
```

**calc.y** file:

```
/* Mini Calculator */
/* calc.y */

%{
#include "heading.h"
int yyerror(char *s);
int yylex(void);
%}

%union{
  int       int_val;
  string*   op_val;
}

%start  input 

%token  <int_val>   INTEGER_LITERAL
%type   <int_val>   exp
%left   PLUS
%left   MULT

%%

input:      /* empty */
        | exp   { cout << "Result: " << $1 << endl; }
        ;

exp:        INTEGER_LITERAL { $$ = $1; }
        | exp PLUS exp  { $$ = $1 + $3; }
        | exp MULT exp  { $$ = $1 * $3; }
        ;

%%

int yyerror(string s)
{
  extern int yylineno;  // defined and maintained in lex.c
  extern char *yytext;  // defined and maintained in lex.c

  cerr << "ERROR: " << s << " at symbol \"" << yytext;
  cerr << "\" on line " << yylineno << endl;
  exit(1);
}

int yyerror(char *s)
{
  return yyerror(string(s));
}
```

here is the error message:

```
$ make
bison -d -v calc.y
cp calc.tab.c bison.c
cmp -s calc.tab.h tok.h || cp calc.tab.h tok.h
g++ -g -Wall -ansi -pedantic -c bison.c -o bison.o
calc.tab.c: In function ‘int yyparse()’:
calc.tab.c:1381: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
calc.tab.c:1524: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
flex calc.lex
cp lex.yy.c lex.c
g++ -g -Wall -ansi -pedantic -c lex.c -o lex.o
calc.lex:8: error: redefinition of ‘int yylineno’
lex.yy.c:349: error: ‘int yylineno’ previously defined here
calc.lex: In function ‘int yylex()’:
calc.lex:23: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
lex.yy.c: At global scope:
lex.yy.c:1105: warning: ‘void yyunput(int, char*)’ defined but not used
make: *** [lex.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're compiling C code with a C++ compiler. If you want flex to generate C++, there is a command line option for that.

The scanner-generated code provides a definition for `yylineno` already.

In C, the following is acceptable:

```
int yylineno;         /* tentative definition */
int yylineno = 1;     /* definition */
```

In C++, it isn't:

```
int yylineno;         /* definition */
int yylineno = 1;     /* another definition: duplicate, error! */
```

Also note that the `-ansi` gcc option applies to the C dialect.

The warnings about string constants are also because of C++. In C++, a string literal like `"abc"` evaluates to a `const char *`, rather than `char *`.

Lastly, note that flex-generated scanners will not automatically contain code that updates `yylineno`. That's turned on with `%option yylineno`. Check the GNU Info manual on Flex.